# Read file starting at second line LabView

Tags: for-loop, readfile, labview

Using the Read from Text File Function I am able to easily read the first line of my file. However I now want it to read the second line. It would be great to just a for loop or something if I could specify the line number somewhere. Is there a way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can read the entire file as lines by right-clicking on the Read From Text File node and selecting "Read Lines".  One read will return an array containing one element for each line and you can work with the lines with regular array handling methods.  If you want to read each line individually, you can by wiring a 1 into the Count input and looping.  Each iteration will return an array with one element (the current line read).  You can get/set the offset (in bytes) to specify where in the file you want to read, but that's not necessary if I read your question correctly.